# Handlebars - require plugin throws the error... Not compiling the template

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

In my app, I am using requirejs with handlbars plugin(https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin), I integrated with my app..

But I am keep getting an error, which i am not able to figureout why?

here is my error:

[image: error screen shot]

my require config file :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl :'bower_components',
    paths: {
        "scripts":'../scripts',
        "jquery":"jquery/jquery.min",
        "underscore" :"underscore-amd/underscore-min",
        "backbone" :"backbone-amd/backbone-min",
        "marionette":"backbone.marionette/lib/backbone.marionette.min",
        "text"  : "requirejs-text/text",
        "hbs":"require-handlebars-plugin/hbs",
        "handlebars":"require-handlebars-plugin/handlebars",
        'i18nprecompile' : 'require-handlebars-plugin/hbs/i18nprecompile',
        'json2' : 'require-handlebars-plugin/hbs/json2'
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            exports: '$'
        },
        "underscore":{
            exports: '_'
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ["jquery","underscore"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "marionette": {
            deps: ["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
            exports: "Marionette"
        }
    }
 });
require(["scripts/main"]);
```

my view file :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'hbs!../template/login1Template.hbs'], 
    function ($,_,Bacbone,hbr) {
        "use strict";
        socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

        socialApp.loginView = Bacbone.View.extend({
            template:_.template(loginTemplate),
            initialize:function(){
                var temp = hbr({adjective: "favorite"});
            }
        });

        return socialApp.loginView;
    }
);
```

Any one help me to sort this issue please? it's sucking my time here!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all...

The problem is, I use `bower.js` to install all my `moudles`. in the plugin, it's not installed properly. some of files are missing from the `git`. manually i updated and the handlebars loading now.